# Destructor delete dynamic array declared in main

Tags: c++

I have declared dynamic array inside int main so my question is that how to delete and release that array in the destructor?? or else I should release that inside main.
delte[] ptr ---
Please answer this simple question to me. Thanks in advance

I have also implement class but declared dynamic array inside main so whats the use of destructor? should I delete inside destructor?

Comment: `main` is not an object, and it doesn't have a destructor. Just delete it before you return. (Actually since the program is exiting anyway the memory would be reclaimed by the OS anyway, but it's good form and habit to do it yourself.)

Comment: destructors ( and constuctors) are member fonctions of objects ( & structs). The 'main' is a classic function, like in C. There in no such destructor.

Comment: Please, show your code. A destructor is something that runs when an *object*'s lifetime ends, and you did not talk about any object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program itself doesn't have a destructor. It starts at the beginning of `main` and ends at the end of `main`. If you need to deallocate some memory you allocated at the beginning of `main`, you should do it before `main` ends:

```
int main() {
  int* arr = new int[10];

  // Do lots of work

  delete[] arr;
}
```

Of course, it would be much better if you encapsulated this memory allocation inside a class using RAII, so that you don't have to deal with it manually. In fact, types already exist for this - the standard library containers (such as `std::vector` or `std::array`).

Comment: then whats the use of destructor in class?? should I not use it in this case?

Comment: @user3215228 The destructor of a class should deallocate any memory it allocated in its constructor.

Comment: @user3215228: if you use a std::vector (as you should), then the *std:vector* destructor will handle the freeing of the memory automatically. Using standard container classes like std::vector will drastically reduce the amount of times you'll have to write your own destructors.

Answer (score 0):

Every scope has exit points. You make use of this and destructors to implement the [RAII](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) idiom. Since you have no class to wrap your data in, you can use the [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/scope_exit/doc/html/scope_exit/tutorial.html) library to define actions to be taken on scope exit.

```
{ // some scope, maybe that of a main function
    double *new_ar = new double[15];
    BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT(new_ar) {
        delete[] new_ar;
    } BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT_END
} // end of scope
```